# System.getenv not finding envrionment variables

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jvm

I am having trouble getting envrionment variables on my Ubuntu insance on EC2.

Here is what is in my `/etc/environment` file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/suredbitsweb"
```

now when I load up a Scala interpreter I try and do the following:

```
^Cubuntu@ip-172-31-35-31:~/suredbits-web$ sudo sbt console
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ubuntu/suredbits-web/project
[info] Set current project to suredbits-web (in build file:/home/ubuntu/suredbits-web/)
[info] Downloading Bower dependencies for suredbits-web
[info] https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF.git#1.0.272
[info] 1.0.272 against https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF.git#~1.0.272
[info] git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-ecies.git#0.10.2
[info] 0.10.2 against git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-ecies.git#^0.10.0
[info] git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore.git#0.10.4
[info] 0.10.4 against git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore.git#^0.10.4
[info] git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers.git#0.10.4
[info] 0.10.4 against git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-explorers.git#~0.10.4
[info] git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-message.git#0.10.1
[info] 0.10.1 against git://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-message.git#~0.10.1
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> System.getenv("PATH");
res0: String = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

scala> System.getenv("DATABASE_URL");
res1: String = null

scala>
```

I have 'rebooted' my EC2 instance hoping that that would help pick up the new environment variable. I also have tried adding the environment variable to my `~/.bashrc` which didn't work.

Comment: Is your DATABASE_URL visible from plain shell with echo $DATABASE_URL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the issue is running it with sudo command. It causes the overriding of your environmental variables. To save your environmental variables, run it with the -E flag, i.e.

`sudo -E sbt console`

Comment: I added more to the OP about how I am launching the Scala interpreter. I'm using the command `sbt console` if that matters at all. This is for a Scala Playframework project

Comment: See my edit and try sudo -E. Looks like your sudo overrides your env variables.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks! Please format your answer to show that the `sudo -E sbt console` was what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, check outputs for `echo $PATH` and `echo $DATABASE_URL`.

Second, check that you launch scala interpreter from right user.

FYI: semicolon is not necessary in scala.

Comment: if he put it into the /etc/environment, then the variables should be system-wide, not user specific.

Comment: Right. So, this advice is irrelevant.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-31:~/suredbits-web$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-31:~/suredbits-web$ echo $DATABASE_URL 
postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/suredbitsweb
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-31:~/suredbits-web$